# Preventing the div element from moving when it toggles some other elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

As you see in here: http://jsfiddle.net/agonl/4o79p3ww/ ,
in the beginning, the on/off button is above its normal position. I know it's because of hiding the other div elements when document is loaded, but how can I fix this moving problem?

Thanks.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".tog").css({"display":"none"});


$(".onoff").click(function(){
$(".button1").fadeToggle();
$(".button2").fadeToggle();
$(".button3").fadeToggle();
$(".button4").fadeToggle();


});

});
```

Comment: `position: absolute`?

Comment: make its position absolute or fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is, that you toggle between `display: none` and `display: block`. If an element has `display: none` the required space for the element does **not** get allocated. You could use `opacity:0` to make the element invisible but still requiring it's space and then toggle it's visibility like this:

```
$(".tog").animate({"opacity": !($(".tog").css("opacity") > 0)}, 500);
```

and if you want the objects with class `.tog` to be invisible from the beginning set this in css:

```
.tog{
    opacity: 0;
}
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2u38y7yp/)

Comment: That did the trick! Thanks.But I have another problem now. http://jsfiddle.net/agonl/z1g1rckq/1/   I want to toggle the on/off button, but I couldn't manage to do that with the methods I saw on the web. What should I do to get the gylphicon element back when I clicked twice?

Comment: @ahgk Use this line when setting the buttons content: `$(".buttonb").html($(".buttonb").children("span.glyphicon").length ? "<h3> John Doe</h3>" : "<span class='glyphicon glyphicon-off'></span>");`

Comment: @ahgk I changed the animate function a little, because i just noticed that clicking on the button twice very fast will break the animation. It's better this way

Answer (score 0):

you can add this:

```
.row {
    min-height:170px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the opacity to make a toggle:

I also simplified your code a little bit.

`$(".tog").animate({ 'opacity': 0});`

http://jsfiddle.net/agonl/4o79p3ww/